# Linux Command: Find & Replace using regex not woking as expected

Tags: regex, linux, shell, ssh, replace

I am trying to replace a path in all php files using regex command, but it isn't working as expected!

I want to replace `'/home/example/public_html` with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '`

I am using the below command in ssh:

```
find /var/www/advertise/ -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/\'\/home\/example\/public_html/\$\_SERVER\[\'DOCUMENT\_ROOT\'\]\ \.\ \'/g' {} \;
```

When i enter the command and hit return, `>` sign follows like:

>

>

>
.. so on as i keep hitting return to execute the command.

Where as below command works perfectly (for replacing `home/example/public_html` with `var/www`):

```
find /var/www/advertise/ -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/home\/example\/public_html/var\/www/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're messing up with the quotes.

- Use a separator other than `/` so that you don't need to escape the `/`
- You don't need to escape in the replacement
- Since you have `'` in the replacement, better use `"s#..#..#"` (i.e. double quotes).  However, you'll need to escape the `$` in the replacement to prevent the shell from trying to expand.

The following might work for you:

```
find /var/www/advertise/ -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i "s#'/home/example/public_html#\$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '#g" {} \;
```